# Trying to print to a file with batch files

Tags: file, batch-file, printing

I'm trying to get this to print into `test.txt`, but it simply says "`ECHO is on.`"

```
ping -n 1 <the ip doesn't matter>
 if errorlevel 0 (
@echo 4>> test.txt
)
```

Comment: Insert a space after the 4 "4 >>"

Answer (score 1):

In batch files there are 10 streams numbered from 0 to 9. stdin is stream 0, stdout is stream 1 and stderr is stream 2. Streams from 3 to 9 are available for what you need.

You can redirect one strem to read from a file with `n<file` where `n` is the stream number used to retrieve the data in the file.

Also, a stream can be used to write to a file. In this case `n>file` indicates that the data written to the stream `n` should be written in the indicated file

The problem with you code is it is saying

```
@echo 4>>test.txt
```

`echo with no parameters to stdout stream (default output stream) while the data sent to stream 4 should be appended to test.txt`

This is a usual problem with data echoed redirected that ends with a digit. You can avoid it changing the order in the command to place the redirection before the command.

```
>>test.txt @echo 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you are trying to redirect 4th stream to a file.

try this:

```
ping -n 1 <the ip doesn't matter>
 if errorlevel 0 (
 (@echo 4)>> test.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A digit directly prior to a redirector redirects the (digit) stream , so `4>` redirects stream 4. This leaves the command as `echo` which will report the current `echo` status (on/off).

The classic syntax mod to cure this problem is

```
>>test.txt echo 4
```

(although other constructs can be implemented)

Another problem with your code is

```
if errorlevel 0 (
```

Well, there *are* rare situations where `errorlevel` can be set to a negative number, but in normal circumstances, `errorlevel` will be 0 or greater than 0.

The `if errorlevel n` statement is interpreted as "if errorlevel is *n* **or** greater than *n*".

Consequently, your `if errorlevel 0` will always be true.

You could use `if %errorlevel%==0` (or `if %errorlevel% EQU 0` which is equivalent) to trigger the true condition only if `errorlevel` is *0* - but this fails if you are using the `if` within a `for` loop. This too has a cure, but we'd be getting too far away from the point were I to go into that fix and its consequences.

Probably the best way is to use `if not errorlevel 1` which will be true if `errorlevel is *ot* 1 or greaer than 1; ie. er, 0 - for all intents and purposes...